# My website has sitelinks but doesn't have a search box below it; is there anything I can do?

Tags: seo, google, sitelinks

See for example [this google query for wikipedia](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=english+wikipedia&aq=f&aqi=g-c10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gs_upl=641%2C1%2C4%2C2%2C88%2C196%2C3%2C1); the first result has both sitelinks and a search box to search within the website.

My site only has sitelinks. Is there anything I can do to make the search box appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the search box appears at the discretion of Google and their algorithms, but I have heard that having a [CSE](http://www.google.com/cse/) set up for your site can increase the likelihood that the box will appear, though this hasn't helped with any of my sites.

Comment: Google decides based on your sites popularity, user keywords and function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late, but you can now mark up your website with JSON-LD to add a search box below your site links.

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview

Comment: I think that is still discretionary isn't it?

Comment: It is yes. I've had the code sat on my site for about 6 months and Google still haven't added a search box for mine.

Answer (score -2):

When your site will have a PR of 8 or more maybe you will get the search box in Google results too.
Just kidding, **I think Google placed it there only for Wikipedia**, but it's interesting, it might be something experimental and maybe one day Google will place such search box for any site that ranks 1st in a his results.

Comment: Whoever place a -1 could at least take the time to explain why.

Comment: I can't tell you why the person down voted you, but I can tell you that you are absolutely wrong about it only being there for Wikipedia: http://www.google.com/search?q=time+and+date  That search for `time and date` should bring up timeanddate.com as the first result with a search box.

Comment: @George Marian: thanks for taking the time to explain, cool, didn't know it.